# extracting text xpath scrapy

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

Hi all I would like to extract all the text from an html block using xpath in scrapy

Let's say we have a block like this:

```
<div>
   <p>Blahblah</p>
   <p><a>Bluhbluh</a></p>
   <p><a><span>Bliblih</span></a></p> 
</div>
```

I want to extract the text as ["Blahblah","Bluhbluh","Blihblih"]. I want xpath to recursively look for text in the div node.
I have heard tried: `//div/p[descendant-or-self::*]/text()` but it does not extract nested elements.

Cheers!
Seb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use XPath's `string()` function on each `p` element:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<div>
...    <p>Blahblah</p>
...    <p><a>Bluhbluh</a></p>
...    <p><a><span>Bliblih</span></a></p> 
... </div>""")
>>> [p.xpath("string()").extract() for p in selector.xpath('//div/p')]
[[u'Blahblah'], [u'Bluhbluh'], [u'Bliblih']]
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(0), [p.xpath("string()").extract() for p in selector.xpath('//div/p')])
[u'Blahblah', u'Bluhbluh', u'Bliblih']
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> selector.xpath('//div/p/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
[u'Blahblah', u'Bluhbluh', u'Bliblih']
```

You were close!
All you had to do is to regard the text of the descendant or self, and not put it as an attribute.
[] are used for "talking" to attributes, in your case the attributes of p, which are non-existent.

Comment: Interestingly, `selector.css('div p ::text').extract()` yields a similar result if you prefer using `css` over `xpath`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get ALL `text` nodes from a given element you need this XPath:

```
//div/p//text()
```

So you code will look like this:

```
text_array = selector.xpath('//div/p//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Elvira Gandelman's solution.

But, there is another clumsy but more intuitive way:

```
response.xpath('(//div/p | //div/p/a | //div/p/a/span)/text()').extract()
['Blahblah', 'Bluhbluh', 'Bliblih']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to tolerate additional dependencies, [html-text](https://pypi.org/project/html-text/) has a method `extract_text`" which normalizes whitespace and removes inline styles. This is helpful if you simply want to return a single string with all child text rather than a list of strings.

```
>>> from html_text import extract_text
>>> extract_text(response.xpath("//div").extract())
'Blahblah\n\nBluhbluh\n\nBliblih'
```